# Error while using 'if' with the count in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

What's wrong with the following? I get a `[: too many arguments` error.

```
if [ 'wc -l pid.txt | awk '{print $1}'' -ge "1" ]
then
    for line in $(cat pid.txt)
    do
        kill $line
    done
else
    rm pid.txt
fi
```

Comment: The single quotes around your command should be back-ticks. Is that a typo in your post or are you using the wrong symbol?

Comment: oops I feel dumb. I am using single quotes and thats the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Vas Your "problem" was the single quotes, but there's a lot more that could be improved.

Answer (score 5):

Improved further thanks to Kusalananda.

- Testing for contents of the file is not necessary as the `while read` loop won't run on an empty file.
- You could then simply use `[ -s pid.txt ] || rm pid.txt` to remove the pid file. *However*, do you really have a reason to keep the file after processing? It seems likely you would want to remove it regardless.

---

```
while read -r line
do
    kill "$line"
done < pid.txt
[ -s pid.txt ] || rm pid.txt
```

A `while read` loop is being used instead 
of `for $(cat ...)`. [Don't read lines with for](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

The `-r` option specifies "do not allow backslashes to escape any characters" which shouldn't really be an issue in a file of pids, but it is best practice to always set unless there is a specific reason not to.

Comment: The initial test can be removed completely as the read loop won't run if it's an empty file.  The `rm` could be replaced by `[ -s pid.txt ] && rm pid.txt` to remove the file if it's empty. The inner loop could be replaced by `xargs -r kill <pid.txt`.

Comment: One could also `grep . pid.txt | while read ...` if there's empty lines in the `pid.txt` file that one wants to avoid.

Comment: `[ -s pid.txt ] || rm pid.txt` to remove if empty, right?

Comment: @ilkkachu Sorry, got the test backwards... duh.